# how to render tinymce editor content in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tinymce, haml

I'm start learning ruby on rails and create blogs. I have integrate tinyMCE editor for blogs content. but i don`t know how to render tinyMCE content for front-end. Now it shows content with as it is html. [image]

Content Rendering Code:

```
%div.container
   %h1.text-center Blogs List
   = link_to 'New Blog', '/admin/blogs/new', :class => 'btn btn-info'            
   = link_to 'logout', '/admin/logout' , :class => 'btn btn-info'
   %table
      %tr
         %th.text-center Title
         %th.text-center Category
         %th.text-center Content
         %th.text-center Feature Image
         %th.text-center{:colspan => 3} Operations
      -@blogs.each do |blog|
         %tr
            %td
               %h4= blog.title
               %td= render blog.categories
            %td.mb-4= blog.text  #editor content
            %td= link_to 'Download', blog.featuredImage_url ,:class=> 'thumbnail'
            %td= link_to 'Show', admin_blog_path(blog) , :class=>'btn btn-info'
            %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_blog_path(blog), :class=> 'btn btn-info'
            %td= link_to 'Destroy', admin_blog_path(blog), :class=> 'btn btn-info', |
               method: :delete,
               data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }
```

Thankyou!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `.sanitize` method like :

```
%td.mb-4= sanitize(blog.text)
```

> Sanitizes HTML input, stripping all tags and attributes that aren’t whitelisted.

You can configure list of whitelisted tags with (for example) :

```
# In config/application.rb
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_tags = ['strong', 'em', 'a']
config.action_view.sanitized_allowed_attributes = ['href', 'title']
```

[.sanitize method doc](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/sanitize)

Comment: undefined method `sanitize' for "<p><strong>gfhfh</strong></p>":String

Comment: @VarinderSohal, fixed, sorry i edited my answer as fast as possible, because sanitize is preferable to use instead of html_safe which expose security problem

Comment: Thank you!! so much bro I appreciate your effort .